# Anaconda, unable to install last version of asammdf

Tags: anaconda, asammdf

I installed recently Anaconda and need to use asammdf.
Standard was 5.8.0 installed, I need 5.21.0.
Running the installer from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/asammdf did not update the package.
Then I installed a new environnement and asammdf and dependencies from scratch. So I could get 5.19.16 installed, but still not the latest.

Running

> conda install -c conda-forge asammdf

from the console returns me the following message:

All requested packages already installed.

But it's not true…

What am I doing wrong ?

In advance thank you for your help.

Here is result of pip freeze on os:

```
aenum==2.2.3
alabaster==0.7.12
anaconda-client==1.7.2
anaconda-navigator==1.9.12
anaconda-project==0.8.3
applaunchservices==0.2.1
appnope==0.1.0
appscript @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/aa928f42-721f-468a-5637-76f7349085f8/volume/appscript_1594840167539/work
argh==0.26.2
argon2-cffi @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c4db8eed-7de0-4d68-400c-2ea7e21d3750/volume/argon2-cffi_1596828478065/work
asammdf==5.19.16
asn1crypto @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/asn1crypto_1596577642040/work
astroid @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/b22b518b-f584-4586-5ee9-55bfa4fca96e/volume/astroid_1592495912194/work
astropy==4.0.1.post1
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==19.3.0
autopep8 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/autopep8_1596578164842/work
Babel==2.8.0
backcall==0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.6.1
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
backports.tempfile==1.0
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
bitarray @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c6d4988e-d50d-45f2-57a8-6d845ccc7c1b/volume/bitarray_1597678765739/work
bitstruct==8.10.0
bkcharts==0.2
bleach==3.1.5
bokeh @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/4dce277b-856c-418f-50a0-50eb18d48058/volume/bokeh_1593187628308/work
boto==2.49.0
Bottleneck==1.3.2
brotlipy==0.7.0
canmatrix==0+unknown
cantools==34.0.0
cchardet==2.1.4
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
cloudpickle @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cloudpickle_1594141588948/work
clyent==1.2.2
colorama==0.4.3
conda==4.8.4
conda-build==3.18.11
conda-package-handling==1.7.0
conda-verify==3.4.2
contextlib2==0.6.0.post1
cryptography==2.9.2
cycler==0.10.0
Cython @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/a8b919bf-06b6-4be5-60d8-71d16518c421/volume/cython_1594833990717/work
cytoolz==0.10.1
dask==2.11.0
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
diff-match-patch @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/diff-match-patch_1594828741838/work
diskcache==4.1.0
distributed @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/0a62cbc9-591a-4d87-7487-c239010d690a/volume/distributed_1594750312816/work
docutils==0.16
entrypoints==0.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
fastcache==1.1.0
filelock==3.0.12
flake8==3.8.3
Flask==1.1.2
fsspec==0.7.4
future==0.18.2
gevent @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/272caec7-c260-4aae-6e70-894795c188a9/volume/gevent_1593009579780/work
glob2==0.7
gmpy2==2.0.8
greenlet==0.4.16
h5py==2.10.0
HeapDict==1.0.1
html5lib @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/html5lib_1593446221756/work
idna @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/idna_1593446292537/work
imageio @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/imageio_1594161405741/work
imagesize==1.2.0
importlib-metadata @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/84197498-cbc0-4436-7ce0-03c4490b7a28/volume/importlib-metadata_1593446431408/work
iniconfig @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/iniconfig_1596827328212/work
intervaltree @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/intervaltree_1594361675072/work
ipykernel @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/73e8766c-12c3-4f76-62a6-3dea9a7da5b7/volume/ipykernel_1596206701501/work/dist/ipykernel-5.3.4-py3-none-any.whl
ipython @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/7ea70a71-5624-4799-50b3-3b90e07922f3/volume/ipython_1593447385860/work
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jdcal==1.4.1
jedi==0.14.1
Jinja2==2.11.2
joblib @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/joblib_1594236160679/work
json5==0.9.5
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyter_client_1594826976318/work
jupyter-console==6.1.0
jupyter-core==4.6.3
jupyterlab==2.1.5
jupyterlab-server @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyterlab_server_1594164409481/work
keyring @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/9f4aa601-8a6f-42a7-4180-58f1f835bf99/volume/keyring_1593109772323/work
kiwisolver==1.2.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
libarchive-c==2.9
llvmlite==0.33.0+1.g022ab0f
locket==0.2.0
lxml @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/0dfefafa-9e58-455e-535c-75e73a127cfd/volume/lxml_1594826856790/work
lz4 @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/70907f0c-3bc5-43d1-77d3-0e51df042440/volume/lz4_1595342290641/work
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/415740a8-e00a-411a-7129-aa05c3842a43/volume/matplotlib-base_1597876353062/work
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune==0.8.4
mkl-fft==1.1.0
mkl-random==1.1.1
mkl-service==2.3.0
mock==4.0.2
more-itertools==8.4.0
mpmath==1.1.0
msgpack==1.0.0
multipledispatch==0.6.0
natsort==7.0.1
navigator-updater==0.2.1
nbconvert==5.6.1
nbformat==5.0.7
networkx @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/networkx_1594377231366/work
nltk @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nltk_1592496090529/work
nose==1.3.7
notebook @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/4befab56-a4d7-490d-6835-d3c47a466e66/volume/notebook_1596838669687/work
numba==0.50.1
numexpr==2.7.1
numpy @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/40d975a3-7e82-44c8-53df-feccdbce8b96/volume/numpy_and_numpy_base_1596233859108/work
numpydoc @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/numpydoc_1594166760263/work
olefile==0.46
openpyxl @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/openpyxl_1594167385094/work
packaging==20.4
pandas @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/8386378f-860c-458e-6b3d-426dc3c0374b/volume/pandas_1596825862710/work
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.5.2
partd==1.1.0
path==13.1.0
pathlib2==2.3.5
pathtools==0.1.2
patsy==0.5.1
pep8==1.7.1
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/05b3bc99-cf9f-44f2-42cf-267ed3a55922/volume/pillow_1594307311725/work
pkginfo==1.5.0.1
pluggy==0.13.1
ply==3.11
prometheus-client==0.8.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.5
psutil==5.7.0
ptyprocess==0.6.0
py @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/py_1593446248552/work
pycodestyle==2.6.0
pycosat==0.6.3
pycparser @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pycparser_1594388511720/work
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0.5
pydocstyle @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pydocstyle_1592848020240/work
pyflakes==2.2.0
Pygments==2.6.1
pylint @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/42ede439-2571-4cb2-513c-394625d2381b/volume/pylint_1592496039330/work
pyodbc===4.0.0-unsupported
pyOpenSSL @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pyopenssl_1594392929924/work
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyrsistent==0.16.0
PySocks==1.7.1
pytest==6.0.1
python-can==3.3.3
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-jsonrpc-server==0.3.4
python-language-server==0.31.7
pytz==2020.1
PyWavelets==1.1.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
pyzmq==19.0.1
QDarkStyle==2.8.1
QtAwesome==0.7.2
qtconsole @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/qtconsole_1592848611704/work
QtPy==1.9.0
regex @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/b2afe0bb-a615-4845-4439-4b4e32958733/volume/regex_1596829787473/work
requests @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/requests_1592841827918/work
rope==0.17.0
Rtree==0.9.4
ruamel-yaml==0.15.87
scikit-image==0.16.2
scikit-learn @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/eab838ab-55a5-40d0-5cbd-f1854d35aa9d/volume/scikit-learn_1592503039331/work
scipy @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/14622691-c324-4e90-5a99-87aced91207b/volume/scipy_1592930535761/work
seaborn==0.10.1
Send2Trash==1.5.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.15.0
snowballstemmer==2.0.0
sortedcollections==1.2.1
sortedcontainers==2.2.2
soupsieve==2.0.1
Sphinx @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sphinx_1597428793432/work
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.4
sphinxcontrib-websupport @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sphinxcontrib-websupport_1597081412696/work
spyder==4.0.1
spyder-kernels==1.8.1
SQLAlchemy @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/701c360b-024a-4c1d-72ce-e82e6bfb4620/volume/sqlalchemy_1593446320654/work
statsmodels==0.11.1
sympy @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/794b4585-6914-43d5-6dd6-9c84fb6d47ed/volume/sympy_1594236608820/work
tables==3.6.1
tblib==1.6.0
terminado==0.8.3
testpath==0.4.4
textparser==0.23.0
threadpoolctl @ file:///tmp/tmp9twdgx9k/threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
toml @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/toml_1592853716807/work
toolz==0.10.0
tornado==6.0.4
tqdm @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/tqdm_1596810128862/work
traitlets==4.3.3
typed-ast==1.4.1
typing-extensions @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/typing_extensions_1592847887441/work
ujson @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/b0b42640-6047-4d8e-4be3-9ef9916c7708/volume/ujson_1592441805801/work
unicodecsv==0.14.1
urllib3 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/urllib3_1597086586889/work
watchdog @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/fe5d349c-1d61-4feb-6b8a-cbc5288b20a8/volume/watchdog_1593447347275/work
wcwidth @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/wcwidth_1593447189090/work
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
wrapt==1.11.2
wurlitzer @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59acb45c-07e7-4304-57af-e84f3889d3ef/volume/wurlitzer_1594753863419/work
xlrd==1.2.0
XlsxWriter==1.2.9
xlwings==0.19.5
xlwt==1.3.0
xmltodict==0.12.0
yapf @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/yapf_1593528177422/work
zict==2.0.0
zipp==3.1.0
zope.event==4.4
zope.interface==4.7.1
```

Running:

```
conda create -n test-env python=3 asammdf
```

returns:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - asammdf

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: _from the console returns me the following message:

All requested packages already installed.

But it's not true…_ Can you share the contents of the environment?

Comment: I just tried the command `conda create -n test-env python=3 asammdf`, and it found version 5.21.0.

Comment: @AMC Hi, I updated my post with your suggestion. Any further tip welcome...

Comment: I should have specified that I use conda-forge as my default channel, can you try `conda create -n test-env -c conda-forge python=3 asammdf` ?